# Can an Android application XYZ set cookies that browser can access?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, cookies

I have a use case where my web page needs to know whether an android application is installed on the device or not? I am aware of the intent method described in the following link
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

But my use case is a little different. I do not intend to open up play store if desired application is not installed. I would rather open up a web page that clearly communicates to the user that he needs to install this application to successfully open the link.

For the use case mentioned above, I am investigating the following approach:
If the application is installed, it sets a cookie which any browser application can access. In the web page I can check via javascript whether such a cookie is present or not. If it is present, I have a signal that desired application to open the link is installed (assuming application was not uninstalled).

However I am not sure whether web views running in different applications do have access to the cookies? Any help in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: No I did not received any answers!